# Linear Regression showing error as Data must be 1D

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression

Trying to run linear regression on the data and getting an error that 'Data must be 1-dimensional'.

Sample data

```
Year    ln_kar
1        4.65
2        5.63
3        6.63
4        2.33
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
data1= pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\3004\\Desktop\\Vaibbhav\\data\\Agricultural cost and price state wise\\crop cost CACP.xlsx',2)
x=data1['Year']
y=data1['ln_kar']
x1 = np.reshape(x,(-1,1))
y1 = np.reshape(y,(-1,1))
model = LinearRegression().fit(x1,y1)
print('intercept: ',model.intercept_)
print('slope: ',model.coef_)
```

Comment: Why do you reshape to `(-1,1)`?  That makes a 2d array.  Do you understand the relation between dimensions and shape?

Comment: I saw a post online to correct my code. And I tried reshaping. What should I try, if not reshaping??

Comment: Run this code fresh, and show the complete error - with traceback.  `fit` does accept (-1,1) shaped inputs.  If you are still getting the "data must be 1d" error, we need a clear picture of where that is happening.

Comment: Playing with some examples, I find that the `1d` error occurs in the `np.reshape` call, not the `fit`.  Try `x1 = x.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)`.  In other words, make a numpy array from the Series, and then reshape it.

Comment: Error that I'm getting when updating the code with 'to_numpy()'.                                  
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: You may have an older version of `pandas` (pre 0.24).  Try `x.values.reshape(-1,1)`.